# Array - Value Jump

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to count the the frequency of starting letters of words in a dictionary, which contains cca 140 000 words. I save the frequencies in the array **count**, with count[0] for the letter a, count [1] for the letter b ... however, when I sum up the array **count**, the value does not equal the total number of words in the dictionary. I found out that if I reduce the dictionary size to 95137, the numbers equal, but as soon as the dictionary has more than 95137 words, the values of count[0] up to count[4] suddenly become immensely big. I have no idea why.. here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("testdic.txt", "r");
    int count[26];
    char buffer[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        count[i] = 0;
    int total = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        count[buffer[0]-97] ++;
        total++;
        if (count[0] > total)            // I used this to find out where the jump occurs
            break;
    }
    printf("%d ", i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        printf("%d " , count[i]);

}
```

Comment: Stack smashing? 96k integers is 400-800kB. And if you have a stack of 1MB, then...

Comment: Put some boundary checking on `buffer[0]-97` before you attempt to use it as an array index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to know why this code produces strange outputs, since you are forgetting several debug checkings.

- `feof` should be used only if your read function fails;
- you don't check `fopen` return value;
- you don't check `scanf` return value;
- you don't check `buffer[0]` value;
- you don't check `buffer` length in `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement `count[buffer[0]-97] ++;` you are considering deriving the index by taking the ascii value of the starting letter and subtracting 97 i.e. ascii value of `a`. I am not sure if you intend to handle a word starting with a capital letter such as `Ascii` where `buffer[0]` is 65 and the expression `buffer[0] - 97` evaluates to a negative integer. This could lead to stack corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the problem, but your code ought to care about whether the words have odd characters in them.
So, simply doing

```
count[buffer[0]-97]
```

is a bit reckless if you ask me! I'd make sure that `buffer[0] >=97 & buffer[0]<97+26` before executing that line. Otherwise, who knows what you are incrementing!

-- could it be that your 95138th word starts with a funny character?

Answer (score 0):

Your `total` variable is declared right after your `count` array - so when you go out of bounds on the array you are messing everything up. A character less than 'a' would be particularly bad - but frankly the first capital letter is enough. Use `count[(buffer[0]-'a')%26]++` - the modulo division forces you to stay in the array. It's a kluge but if that works you can start looking for bad characters.